# Angular 4 Web api call

Tags: angular

i have a click method for login,. The method compare username e password insert by users with username e password contains in the database

```
autenticato(username, password){
this.http.get('http://localhost:5200/' + 'api/Dipendente/GetLogin/?userName=' + username + '&passWord=' + password).map(result => result.json()).subscribe(result => {  
  this.login = result;
  console.log(this.login);
}, error => console.error(error));
return this.login;}
```

my web api method :

```
public IQueryable GetLogin(string userName, string passWord)
    {
        UfficioEntities db = new UfficioEntities();
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        var user=db.Dipendente.Where(x => x.Username == userName && x.Password == passWord);
        if (user != null)
            return user;
        else
            return null;}
```

the call always fails with error 404 except for the times that it is successful even with the same inputs. Can someone help me solve?

the error that shows the console is:

```
_body: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }headers: Object { _headers: Map, _normalizedNames: Map }ok:falsestatus: 0statusText: ""type: 3url: null
```

Comment: What is the exact version of angular are you using and which http module ?

Comment: Subscribe should be before map function.

Comment: @ Houssem Romdhani no you are wrong? what is the point of applying map operator after subscribing? you apply the Map operator first to transform the value and then subscribe it.

Comment: i test my web api with postman ,but when i call web api from angular .....
`_body: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }
​
headers: Object { _headers: Map, _normalizedNames: Map }
​
ok: false
​
status: 0
​
statusText: ""
​
type: 3
​
url: null`